Flutter as a PWA that can launch offline
First question : Is Flutter PWA still a thing? Documentation about this seems to be very sparse. Most things I can find is : "it should work automatically'.
Currently I just want a very simple 1 page flutter webapp, without any network requests, to be installable as a PWA, and be startable when the device is offline.
What I already did is in index.html
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">


<script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/mapp/flutter_service_worker.js?v=20241210_1149'); // replace '<timestamp>' with your latest version/timestamp
        });
      }
    </script>

In the build output I can see that the correct name is set for $FLUTTER_BASE_HREF
I also modified manifest.json. And setted the complete URL in start_url
Now I can actually install the app on mobile devices.
But when I switch off network, I only see the dinosaur when launching the app.
When checking with developer tools I can see that the survice worker is actually running. And I can also see some things in the cache.
Are there any good tutorials on Flutter PWA that still work in 2024?
Or any pointers on how to make it work?
Or is Flutter PWA, or PWA in general, not a thing in anymore in 2024?
